# Pagebreak within a larger environment of facing pages (reledpar)

Tags: page-breaking, reledmac, reledpar

Again a question regarding pagebreaks with facing pages in `reledmac` and `reledpar`. I'd like to insert some pagebreaks manually to prevent having only one line (or a single chapter/section title) of a paragraph on the previous parallel pages.

The problem is, that within my large document the `\ledpb` command called after `\pstart` causes a nearly blank page with one line of the previous paragraph on it before the correct pagebreak is made. I tried also to experiment a bit with the goalfraction (`\renewcommand*{\setgoalfraction}{x.y}`) but it seems to have no effect at all. Is there any hint how a pagebreak in this situation could be made?

Comment: Thirst, you should not do `\renewcommand*{\setgoalfraction}{x.y}` but just `\setgoalfraction{x.y}`. Then, I don't understand exactly what you need, but I think you problem could be solve with \ledpbsetting{after}. Anyway, I MWE is welcome.

Comment: Thank you I tried it out. And indeed something is moving. Maybe my document is too big to see changes after just typesetting a few times. But maybe a stupid question: Where do I have to call the `\setgoalfraction` command? If I call it outside the pages environment I get an number output directly in the pdf. But within the `\pstart […] \pend` section it seems to be without effect. As dicussed in another thread here.

Comment: It should be in the preamble. I have tried again, and it is working, without typessetting number.

Comment: Ah ok, typesetting the number occured only with the `\renewcommand` when putting it inside the body of the document. I've removed the `\renewcommand` now everywhere. It was a relict of `eledmac`. But I wanted to change the goalfraction nearly for each chapter by putting it outside the Pages environment. As far as I tried it out, it is working. It would be very practical if I can change the parameter for each chapter because they're quite different. Am I expected to be running into problems by changing it within the document?

Comment: you can change it between any pages environnement, but not inside (are you could have problem).